# C# Bitmap class with matrix transformation

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap, coordinate-transformation

I am using the matrix class to shear my image. But how do I calculate the expected width and height of the new bitmap?

```
Bitmap bitmap=new Bitmap(x,y);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Shear(1, 0.2);            
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.Transform = matrix;
graphics.DrawImage(imageToSkew, 0, 0);
bitmap.Save(outputstream,imageformat);
```

Comment: You need to calculate the Bounding Rectangle of the result.  That means you have to know the size of the result.  Math will be involved.

Comment: @Plutonix any formulas?

Comment: You should transform the rectangle defining the bitmap boundaries, using the same transform you're using to transform the bitmap itself. That will tell you where the corners of the original bitmap get moved to. Then you can use those to determine the smallest "normal" rectangle (i.e. rectangle that is aligned with the axes) that can contain the transform rectangle. This works for any transform: shear, rotation, scaled, whatever.

Comment: @PeterDuniho didn't quite get you... Can I see some code?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th40x9c1(v=vs.110).aspx